# How to simulate a column addition and table reordering in KDB

Tags: kdb

I would like to know how much time would it take to add a column or a number of columns to my HDB and reorder them.
How could I go about doing this ?

I thought about adding and removing a dummy column to the said HDB and compare the start time and end time, but the problem is , this is a PROD hdb .

Is there a mathematical formula that would allow me to approximate how long such an operation would take ?

Comment: Adding columns is generally very fast, it should take only minutes to add one blank column to a 30 year database.

Answer (score 4):

The dbmaint library is available https://github.com/KxSystems/kdb/blob/master/utils/dbmaint.md

It has an `addcol` function for adding an extra blank columns.
It is limited in speed more by disk write speed. As they are blank to start writing with compression on makes a lot of sense and will be faster. Testing adding the columns on a subset of data is the best way to test for speed.

The `reordercols` function is also available. It is very fast to run as it only has to edit small `.d` files to perform it's task.

https://code.kx.com/q/kb/splayed-tables/

If you need to re-sort the tables after the maintenance this is a much slower task. How long it takes depends on:

1. The datatypes of columns involved
2. The number of rows
3. The number of columns
4. Whether compression is on or off and what settings are being used
5. The specs of the server involved CPU and IO speed of the disk system

Rather than using a formula with high complexity and many input factors it is usually easiest to perform a test of the task you wish to complete on a subset of data on ideally as identical as possible hardware. Then you can estimate out from this how long the whole task will take.

Some notes also on:

- https://kx.com/blog/kdb-q-insights-database-maintenance-with-q/

Comment: Worth noting that since you will be writing contiguous bytes for each new column, a quick test using dd utilities or similar (even setting a dummy column on the same mount) should be representative.